# Retina icon ignored in Qt project

Tags: qt, retina-display

I am trying to add retina icons to [DB Browser for SQLite](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser) and I can't get it to work. I added a 32x32 file suffixed with `@2x.png` but it is ignored.

I also tried adding it to the [icons.qrc](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/blob/master/src/icons/icons.qrc) file to no avail. `NSHighResolutionCapable` is added to the [plist file](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/blob/master/src/app.plist#L74-L75) too. I added `a.setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps);` in the [main.cpp](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/blob/master/src/main.cpp) file too.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://tano.si/2013/10/26/how-to-support-retina-screens-in-qt/

Comment: @AlexanderVX, Doesn't help me. I guess I am trying to use the `Integrated Icons` part, because I have some files saved on disk, which sometimes are not even loaded directly by the app. And that articles says that that just works.

Comment: In main.cpp try this: QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling); // before QApplication app(argc, argv); and then use only higher grade icons everywhere. That is for Qt 5.6 and newer.